# Matconvnet - How to make imdb.mat (image database) with my own picture and label

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, matconvnet

MatLab newbie here. I want to use CNN for classify my data, i have 46 folder with 5 picture each inside. My data is Hiragana text, it's like alphabet.

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsKCFHkQ-Ik) and it's have imdb.mat file already. I already seek the answer and still cannot figure it how to make my own imdb. Really need step-by-step explanation and how my folder should structured.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the new version of Matconvnet (March 2017) recently add [cnn_toy_data](https://github.com/vlfeat/matconvnet/blob/master/examples/custom_imdb/cnn_toy_data.m) for making custom imdb. My question solved.